# Solve in positive integers $\frac{x^{2}}{y}+\frac{y^{2}}{x}=9$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Solve in positive integers $\frac{x^{2}}{y}+\frac{y^{2}}{x}=9$
By inspection we see $x=4$ and $y=2$ is a solution. But are there any more solutions? I have tried to convert the equation to inequality by CS but it is not taking me anywhere. I have tried order relationship $x \geq y$ but then it is becoming $\frac{2y^{2}}{x} \leq 9 $ and i am stuck in this point how to proceed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By AM-GM, $\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{x}\geq 2\sqrt{xy}$, hence $xy$ is at most $20$.

Moreover, the original equation is equivalent to:
$$ (x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2) = 9xy, $$
but $x^2-xy+y^2\geq xy$, hence $x+y$ is at most $9$. So we have to check very few cases to be sure that the only solutions in $\mathbb{N}^2$ are the trivial ones.

Comment: thanks. I have got $x+y \leq 9$ but missed $xy$ is at most 20.

Comment: (+1) I was working on the same idea, but you got there first. Hopefully, you include $(2,4)$ and $(4,2)$ in the "trivial" cases.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a straightforward proof based on considerations of divisibility.

Let $x=ad$, $y=bd$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$.  The equation becomes $(a^3+b^3)d=9ab$, which implies $a$ and $b$ individually divide $d$.  Since $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, we must have $d=ab\delta$, hence $9=(a^3+b^3)\delta$.  It's clear that $a$ and $b$ can't both be odd, so it's easy to see that we can only have $\{a,b\}=\{1,2\}$, with $\delta=1$. So the only solutions come from $\{x,y\}=\{2,4\}$.